# Is there a way to disable SSL/TLS for GitHub Pages?

Tags: http, https, hosting, github-pages

I have been looking for a place to store some of my XML schemas publicly without actually having to host them. I decided [GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com/) would be the ideal platform. I was correct except that I cannot figure out how to turn off SSL/TLS. **When I try to fetch my pages with plain old HTTP I get a `301 Moved Permanently` response.**

So obviously this isn't a big deal. Worst case scenario it takes a little longer to download my schemas, and people generally only use schemas that they've already cached anyway. But is there really no way to turn this off?

Comment: Why not just make the request over HTTPS?

Comment: Because it is simple to proxy HTTP. And it is safe if you verify the hash afterwards. With HTTPS you need to distribute your root certificate to use a proxy. That is one of the reasons why linux packages are often downloaded using http.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From [github](https://help.github.com/articles/securing-your-github-pages-site-with-https/) help :

> HTTPS enforcement is required for GitHub Pages sites created after June 15, 2016 and using a github.io domain.

So, you have two solutions :

- find a github.io repository older than June 15, 2016
- [set a custom domain](https://help.github.com/articles/using-a-custom-domain-with-github-pages/) name on your github.io

Comment: Custom domain doesn't help as of now. Redirects to HTTPS.

Answer (score 3):

> But is there really no way to turn this off?

No, and a simple [`curl -L`](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-L) would follow the redirection and get you the page content anyway.

For instance (get an xml file in a tree structure):

```
vonc@vonvb C:\test
> curl --create-dirs -L -o .repo/local_manifests/local_manifest.xml -O -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/legaCyMod/android_local_manifest/cm-11.0/local_manifest.xml
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   530  100   530    0     0   1615      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  1743

vonc@voncvb C:\test
> tree /F .
C:\TEST
└───.repo
    └───local_manifests
            local_manifest.xml
```

Comment: I understand that I can follow redirects, but a redirect from HTTP to HTTPS takes even longer than HTTPS alone.

Comment: @WilliamRosenbloom True, I agree. Is that a concern in your case though? Do you have to fetch that many pages in such a short period that the redirect overhead begins to have an actual impact?

Comment: No honestly none of this ***really*** matters at the moment. I even admit that in the last paragraph of my question. I'm just curious because it seems like the convention is to use plain HTTP and I feel like that would be more professional.

Comment: @WilliamRosenbloom with http2, the convention shifts more and more to https. (https://http2.github.io/faq/#does-http2-require-encryption)